# a doubt on cycle decomposition in Dummit's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups

I have a doubt in Dummit's Abstract Algebra on page115 :

> Let $A = \{ 1 , 2, . . . , n \}$ , let $\sigma$ be an element of $S_n$ and let $G=\langle\sigma\rangle$ . Then $\langle\sigma\rangle$ acts on $A$ and so, by Proposition 2, it partitions $\{ 1 , 2, . . . , n\}$ into a unique set of (disjoint) orbits. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be one of these orbits and let $x\in\mathcal{O}$ . By (the proof of) Proposition 2 applied to ${\color{red}{A = \mathcal{O}}}$ we see that there is a bijection between the left cosets of $G_x$ in $G$ and the elements of $\mathcal{O}$ , given explicitly by
> $$
> \sigma^ix\mapsto\sigma^iG_x\ .
> $$

My doubt is about the red part "${\color{red}{A = \mathcal{O}}}$", I think it is not certainty true:

> Suppose $\mathcal{O}_x=A$ then for all $a\in A$ there must exist some $i\in A$ s.t. $\sigma^i\cdot x=\sigma^i(x)=a$ .But since $\sigma$ is arbitrary, it may not always hold.
>
> For instance, let $\sigma=(1\ 2)\in S_3$ and $x=1$ then $\mathcal{O}_x=\{1,2\}\ne\{1,2,3\}=A$ .

So, is it a typo?

Comment: When you say "A=O", you mean that now you restrict the group action to act only on the set "O".

Comment: Oh, It is my misunderstanding of its meaning. Thanks!@Kendall

Comment: Dummits means he applies his proposition 2, where $G$ acted on some set (called $A$ in that proposition) to the case where that set is the orbit $\mathcal O.$ I.e. he restricts the action to that orbit. He does not mean that this orbit is the whole set unluckily also called $A$ right now.

Comment: It's Dummit & Foote, not just Dummit.

Comment: Which edition are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is Dummit and Foote. The 3rd one.@Shaun

Comment: Thanks for your answering@AnneBauval , I realize that $\mathcal{O}=A$ and $A=\mathcal{O}$ are not the same things.